# How to get all Fields of specific FieldType?

Tags: entities, 8

What I'm trying to do is ->

```
 $fields = [];
  $fields = $entity->getFieldDefinitions();  
  foreach ($fields as $field) {
    if ($field->field_type == 'type') {
      $test = $field->field_type;
    }
  }
```

Unfortunately I couldn't find a neat method to select my fields by type, so I thought unless Drupal won't give me one I write my own.
But Drupal restrict me on that also with this ->
Fatal error: Cannot access protected property

> Fatal error: Cannot access protected property
>   Drupal\field\Entity\FieldConfig::$field_type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You code is OK, only that you are trying to read the protected property `field_type`. Instead use the method:

```
$field->getType()
```

Reference: [public function FieldDefinitionInterface::getType()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21FieldDefinitionInterface.php/function/FieldDefinitionInterface%3A%3AgetType/8.2.x)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a quick rundown how I retrieved this information:

- Opened up FieldConfig (`core/modules/field/src/Entity/FieldConfig.php`)
- Searched for `$field_type`
- Nothing useful
- Went to the base class FieldConfigBase (`core/lib/Drupal/Core/Field/FieldConfigBase.php`)
- Search results:

  - First one: `protected $field_type;` (okay protected, as expected. This is why it doesn't work)
  - Second result `public function getType() {
    return $this->field_type;
    }`

    This seems to be what we want.
  - Let's see which interface defines this method: My IDE tells me: `\Drupal\Core\Field\FieldDefinitionInterface::getType`

For a little bit nicer code, here is a function which returns all field definitions (note: this are not the fields actually having the values) by field type:

```
function getFieldDefinitionsByType(FieldableEntityInterface $entity, $field_type) {
  $fields = $entity->getFieldDefinitions();
  $fields_by_type = array_filter($fields, function (FieldDefinitionInterface $field_definition) use ($field_type) {
    return $field_definition->getType() == $field_type;
  });
  return $fields_by_type;
}
```